# how to fetch the variable value of .ts file in .scss file?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using a css only pie chart. I want to use the value of **this.performance** in my scss to define the **percentage**.How can i control my scss file from .ts file?
  My css code in scss is shown below:

```
$configs: (
  chart-one: (
    svgSize: 200px,
    percentage: 32,
    strokeWidth: 1px,
    backgroundColor: #305556,
    foregroundColor: #79be9b,
    labelColor: #c6e8d7,
    labelFontSize: 2.5rem,
    duration: 3s,
    animationDelay: 1s
  )
);
```

My ts code:

```
this.total=data[0][0].TOTAL;
    this.completed=data[2][0].COMPLETED;
 this.performance=((this.completedontime/this.total)*100);
```

**Requirement-->**  How can i use the value of **this.performance** in place of **percentage:32**

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to do so. Sass and TypeScript are separate technologies, unaware of each other's existence. Angular doesn't even know you were using Sass in the first place because it's compiled down to CSS before Angular reaches it. Of course, the biggest issue here is that **Sass variables are built-time artifacts**.

That said, it's *probably* possible to do so **in theory** by using a custom webpack loader that will go over a statically analyzable TypeScript file, but there's no need for it because you can already to the same with Sass loops and conditional statements.

If you need to impact CSS during runtime, what you should use are [CSS custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*). They can be accessed via JavaScript DOM API, which means you can use it in your Angular code.